# How to add task dependencies in Gradle?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build

I'm trying to write a task named `stage` like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    base
}

val clean = "clean"
val build = "build"

tasks.register("stage") {
    dependsOn(clean, build)
}

tasks[build].dependsOn(clean)
```

The problem is that when I run `./gradlew stage` it doesn't run `clean`, nor `build`. This is a multiproject build and I have 3 subprojects with Kotlin code.

How do I get Gradle to run `./gradlew clean build` whenever I type `./gradlew stage`? This is clearly not a solution, and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

I also tried this, but it didn't work either. It runs the tasks I want but at the end it runs `clean` and I end up with no `build` folder:

```kotlin
tasks.register("stage") {
    subprojects.forEach { project ->
        val clean = project.tasks.first { it.name.contains("clean") }
        val build = project.tasks.first { it.name.contains("build") }
        build.dependsOn(clean)
        dependsOn(build)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the issues in your code is running the command:

```rb
build.dependsOn(clean)
```

Instead try:

```
tasks{
     register("stage"){
       dependsOn(clean, build)
    }
}
```

Remember that tasks{} is a container and by scoping the code inside we have access to the other tasks as well.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to define the ordering using `mustRunAfter`

```
tasks.register("stage") {
    subprojects.forEach { project ->
        val clean = project.tasks.first { it.name.contains("clean") }
        val build = project.tasks.first { it.name.contains("build") }
        build.dependsOn(clean)
        build.mustRunAfter(clean)
        dependsOn(build)
    }
}
```

From the docs of [Task Dependencies and Task Ordering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#N18A16):

> Dependencies to a task are controlled using Task.dependsOn(java.lang.Object[]) or Task.setDependsOn(java.lang.Iterable), and Task.mustRunAfter(java.lang.Object[]), Task.setMustRunAfter(java.lang.Iterable), Task.shouldRunAfter(java.lang.Object[]) and Task.setShouldRunAfter(java.lang.Iterable) are used to specify ordering between tasks.

This documentation in Gradle about [ordering tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks) can explain tasks ordering, and why you need a combination of `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter` for your use case:

> Note that “B.mustRunAfter(A)” or “B.shouldRunAfter(A)” does not imply any execution dependency between the tasks:
> It is possible to execute tasks A and B independently. The ordering rule only has an effect when both tasks are scheduled for execution.

Answer (score -1):

its much simpler

```
plugins {
    base
}

allprojects {
    task stage() {
        dependsOn(clean, build)
    }
}
```

so when you run stage - it should do clean and build

Comment: This is for Groovy, but I'm using the Kotlin DSL.